# NetBeans and PHP on the Mac: How to set it up?

Tags: php, macos, netbeans

I'm new to this and want to start coding PHP with NetBeans.

Is there a step-by-step instruction on how to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those might help :

- [NetBeans IDE 6.7.1 Installation Instructions](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/install.html#install_mac)
- [Running NetBeans IDE on Mac OS X](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansMacOSX)
- [Using NetBeans IDE on Mac OS X](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html)

And, of course, for PHP Development :

- [Developing PHP Applications In NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html)

Answer (score 1):

- [Installing Netbeans on Mac](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/install.html#install_mac)
- [Configuring PHP in OSX](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/internet/phpeasyway.html)

I hope this helps